# streambuilder not displaying data in list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display a list of employees in my app. Here's the code I got so far:

```
return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 20),
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.12),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text("Employees",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Employees").snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: Text("Fetching data..."));
                } else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['name']));
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text("hol up");
                }
              }),
        ],
      );
```

When I run the app, it just shows 'Employees' and 'hol up' in a column. Why does the list of employees not show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by simply adding shrinkWrap: true in my listview.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also get the data from the indexed document.

```
 ListTile(
   title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['name']));
```